# Objective-C: Move frame while key is pressed

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, animation, nsimageview

I'm trying to move an NSImageView while key is being pressed. 
Right now I have a boolean value that gets assigned true when keyDown is called, 
and false when keyUp is called. 
How could I animate an NSImageView to be moving while key is down?

For example, an image should move to the left while the left-arrow key is pressed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start a repeating NSTimer in your keyDown method, and in the timer's selector method just subtract a certain amount from the image view's frame.origin.x. In the keyUp method, you would invalidate the timer.